# Basic requirements for using facebook sdk in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

I want to know the basic requirements such as

- codeigniter version
- php version
- facebook for php sdk version

I was trying the facebook sdk version 3 with php 5.3.5, codeigniter 2.2. Will it work?
Please guide me.

Comment: Only one way to find out!

Comment: @iswinky Is it? How to find it?

Comment: And for the one who voted this question down, I didn't get the info regarding it, so I asked it here. It's not a crime if you are having less knowledge about something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure it works. Would recommend that you actually start building it and if it does not work, post here in stackoverflow with the errors and i am sure the community will help.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download & setup folders

I’ll try to make this as short and sweet as possible:

```
Download the Facebook SDK for PHP from GitHub
```

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/archive/master.zip

```
Create a folder in your application/libraries folder called facebook
Move the Facebook folder in src from the Facebook SDK to the facebook folder you just created.
```

Step 2: Create & define config variables

You’ll also need to setup some config variables. Either in the application/config/config.php or your own config file — which I’d suggest you do — create the following variables:

```
<?php
$config['facebook']['api_id'] = 'YOUR APP ID';
$config['facebook']['app_secret'] = 'YOUR APP SECRET';
$config['facebook']['redirect_url'] = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/login';
$config['facebook']['permissions'] = array(
'email',
'user_location',
'user_birthday'
);
```

view raw 1492-1.php hosted with ❤ by GitHub

Now that you’ve got the files and configuration setup, you’ll need to create the Facebook library for CodeIgniter. You’ll use this to bridge the grab between your CI application and the Facebook SDK.
Step 3: Create the CodeIgniter library

Create a file in your application/libraries/facebook folder called Facebook.php. This is where all the magic is going to happen. Depending on how you use it, you may want to autoload the library or just load it in the controller you’ll be using it for… up to you.

> This by no means is a complete library, but shows you how to use the
>   API to create methods enabling you to access them in your controllers.

```
application/libraries/facebook/facebook.php:

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {
session_start();
}

// Autoload the required files
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/vendor/autoload.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;


class Facebook {
var $ci;
var $helper;
var $session;
var $permissions;

public function __construct() {
$this->ci =& get_instance();
$this->permissions = $this->ci->config->item('permissions', 'facebook');

// Initialize the SDK
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $this->ci->config->item('api_id', 'facebook'), $this->ci->config->item('app_secret', 'facebook') );

// Create the login helper and replace REDIRECT_URI with your URL
// Use the same domain you set for the apps 'App Domains'

$this->helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $this->ci->config->item('redirect_url', 'facebook') );

if ( $this->ci->session->userdata('fb_token') ) {
$this->session = new FacebookSession( $this->ci->session->userdata('fb_token') );

// Validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
try {
if ( ! $this->session->validate() ) {
$this->session = null;
}
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
// Catch any exceptions
$this->session = null;
}
} else {
// No session exists
try {
$this->session = $this->helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
// When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
}
}

if ( $this->session ) {
$this->ci->session->set_userdata( 'fb_token', $this->session->getToken() );

$this->session = new FacebookSession( $this->session->getToken() );
}
}

/**
* Returns the login URL.
*/
public function login_url() {
return $this->helper->getLoginUrl( $this->permissions );
}

/**
* Returns the current user's info as an array.
*/
public function get_user() {
if ( $this->session ) {
/**
* Retrieve User’s Profile Information
*/
// Graph API to request user data
$request = ( new FacebookRequest( $this->session, 'GET', '/me' ) )->execute();

// Get response as an array
$user = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();

return $user;
}
return false;
}
}
```

The library above will give you access to the Facebook SDK Graph API. It creates and saves the Facebook token in session so you can access it later for calls to the API.
Example Usage

Once you’ve loaded the Facebook library you created above, you’ll have access to it within your controllers with the following:

```
$this->facebook->METHOD_NAME();
```

For example, if you wanted to get the login URL (where user’s grant access):

```
$login_url = $this->facebook->get_login_url();

$fbuserid = $this->facebook->fb_userid();

            $fb_user_sel_fields = "";
            $user_profile = $this->facebook->fb_user_profile($fbuserid, $fb_user_sel_fields);
```

print_r( $user_profile );